# Can argparse associate positional arguments with named arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to associate positional arguments with the "argument state" which exists when they occur.  For example, the following command line:

```
script.py -m 1 foo -r 2 bar -r 7 baz -m 6 quux
```

Should produce the following associations:

```
foo:  m=1, r=0 (default value for r)
bar:  m=1, r=2
baz:  m=1, r=7
quux: m=6, r=7
```

Can this be done with the `argparse` module?

Comment: Are the set of "argument states" constant?  e.g. do you know up front if only `('foo','bar','baz','quux' ...) will ever be used?  Or is the user able to put anything they want whereever they want?

Comment: @mgnilson — Anything wherever they want; what I'm looking at is a list of filenames and processing options.  Based on `argparse`'s handling of positional arguments, I'm thinking this can't be done without a model-breaking custom Action, which is what I'm currently playing around with.

Comment: I was thinking about custom actions too, but that's tricky because argparse seems to assume that all the positional arguments are given together.  The only remedy is to use `nargs='*'` everywhere and then inside all your actions check to make sure you got the right number.  (which seems fragile at best).  Of course, this gets a lot easier if you allow:  `-m 1 -f foo -r 2 -f bar -r 7 -f baz -m 6 -f quux`

Comment: Is it safe to assume that every positional argument is a filename and that nothing else is?

Comment: @mgilson — Yes; each named argument takes exactly one parameter (`nargs=1`) and everything else is a filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be useful to you, but this problem seems to be easiest if you can break `sys.argv` into pieces -- Essentially, you need to be able to figure out which pieces are supposed to be "positional" arguments (they're not actually positional since as you say, they can occur anywhere) and which pieces are supposed to be some sort of argument.  In the example below, I've set it up to work with your example, but you could just as easily split `sys.argv` on files -- or on a certain kind of file.  The `condition` function is up to you to write.  The rest will (hopefully) be self-explanatory.

```
import argparse
import sys
import copy
import os

def split_list(lst,condition):
    current=[]
    out=[current]
    for arg in lst:
        current.append(arg)
        if(condition(arg)):
            current=[]
            out.append(current)

    return out


parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m',action='store')
parser.add_argument('-r',default='0',action='store')
#pieces=split_list(sys.argv[1:],os.path.isfile)
pieces=split_list(sys.argv[1:],lambda x: x in ('foo','bar','baz','quux'))
options={} #use collections.OrderedDict if order matters -- or some more suitable data structure.
default=argparse.Namespace()
for args in pieces:
    if(not args):
        continue
    ns=copy.deepcopy(default)
    default=parser.parse_args(args[:-1],namespace=ns)
    options[args[-1]]=default

print (options)
```

Comment: Interesting idea! Changing the lambda to `x[0] != "-"` should work for splitting the args effectively (I think the basic syntax I propose makes it unreasonable to accept filenames starting with `-` anyway).  Let me play around with this.

Comment: @BenBlank changing the lambda to `not x.startswith('-')` was my first thought too, but it fails on your test example since '1' doesn't start with '-

Comment: I got around that by [replacing the lambda](https://gist.github.com/3026853) with hard-coded logic which refuses to split after a named parameter.  With that change, this is doing exactly what I need!  Thanks for the help.